# Can't connect to Apache remotely

Tags: apache, redhat, remote-access, iptables

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I've installed apache via `yum install httpd`. When I execute `curl localhost` it responds beatifully with the apache test page. However connecting remotely via web browser(typing the ip address) results in Webpage not available (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) in Chrome. This is the output from `netstat -ntlp`:

> ```
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      700/sshd       
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      930/master     
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2010/httpd     
> tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      700/sshd       
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      930/master
> ```

And this is the output of `iptables -L`

> ```
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your netstat output says port 80 is listening on tcp6 not tcp. i.e ipv6 not ipv4

Comment: Well, actually this is just the way it's displayed for apache. It doesn't mean it will accept only ipv6 connections. Still looking for suggestions.